# como hacer que mediante un solo modelo tener varios modelos

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Tengo estos dos modelos, que necesito que esten en uno solo modelo, para poder ser utilizado en un controlador.

Modelo numero one

```
  public class Preuba
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string? Apellido { get; set; }    
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
```

Modelo numero two

```
 public class Usuario
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
 
    }
```

Comment: Creas un tercer modelo, e integras el modelo 1 y el modelo 2.

Comment: Si la respuesta cumplió resolvió la pregunta, marca la respuesta como aceptada mediante click en el check verde, de ese modo se mantiene la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tener múltiples modelos, se crea un "ViewModel":

```
public class Preuba
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Apellido { get; set; }    
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }

}

public class UsuarioPreubaViewModel 
{
    public Preuba Preuba {get; set;}
    public Usuario Usuario {get; set;}
}
```

Ahora que ya tienes el ViewModel, se procede a trabajar de la misma manera: creas una nueva instancia y le asignas las propiedades. En el View, el modelo es el ViewModel y al momento de mostrar alguna propiedad, estarías como `model.Preuba.Name`.

Hace tiempo, realicé este workshop un ASPNetMVC, abarca un buen fundamento, espero lo disfrutes:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY